# Lock Screen with Button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am pretty new to WP8 development.

I would like to know that can we create a custom Lock Screen, like in Android.
I would like to know that can we put a button on lock screen on click of which we can unlock the phone. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Custom lock screens as you describe are not supported.

Comment: Thanks.. i was afraid of that. came across this link. looks like i will have to lock each and every application in the phone now http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/creating-an-app-lock-for-windows-phone-8-with-numeric-password/